# Trying to update to latest NPM version but existence of npx is blocking it

Tags: npm, npx

I would like to update to the latest npm version on a mac, so of course I ran

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

but I got the following error message

```
rm not removing /usr/local/bin/npm as it wasn't installed by /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN rm not removing /usr/local/bin/npx as it wasn't installed by /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/npx
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/npx'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/npx
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

Ok, I would like to not run --force to overwrite files recklessly - so how do I get npm to install the latest version in this case?

Comment: I have the same situation after installing node with brew.

Comment: well bad news, I finally just swore and ran with force. Didn't have any bad results though so not altogether bad news.